# Don't sync files during Matlab execution in Dropbox (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, sync, dropbox, matlab

I'm a strong Dropbox user. I usually log in (via SSH) to my Linux machine and use Matlab on a Dropbox folder which automatically syncs everything. However, at this moment, my code generates a lot of huge *.mat* files that I don't want to sync between my two machines.

It is possible to avoid that? Do I need a Matlab command, a terminal command, a bash script?

Comment: @Dennis thank you for the editing. However anyone knows how to help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for you, you can temporarily pause Dropbox syncing and enable it after you completed your work with [this](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Enable_Disable_LAN_Sync) python script. It only works for Dropbox 0.7.x and 0.8.x though.

Also, there are lots of Dropbox addons on [this](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Dropbox_Addons) webpage for several coding languages and platforms.

Moreover, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707780/call-python-function-from-matlab) method you can call python scripts from Matlab.

Comment: nice trick, I'll try to call the script from matlab or writing one on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a setup like this:

1. One folder for things that need to be synchronized, lets call this include
2. One folder for things that don't need to be synchronized, lets call this exclude

Normally you can just work in the 'include' folder, but when you have some files to save, just set their saving path to the 'exclude' directory.

### Example:

```
filePath = fullfile('C','myBigFile.mat')
save(filePath,'myBigVariable')
```